# WP8 Listbox still scrolling after ScrollViewer has been disabled

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, scroll

I want a Listbox to be not scrollable. Disabling the Scrollviewer's ScrollbarVisibility doesn't work properly.

I can't provide an SSCCE, since this is a WP8 project. However, create a new WP8 project, then copy this to MainPage.xaml inside the Grid named "ContentPanel"

```
<ListBox x:Name="list" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
```

And copy this to MainPage.xaml.cs below `InitializeComponent();`:

```cs
List<string> testList=new List<string>();
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
    testList.Add("Some text with a number "+i);
}

this.list.ItemsSource=testList;
```

Now deploy the app.

You cannot scroll the Listbox, when you move your finger along the y-axis. However, when you move your finger diagonal across the screen, it will still scroll. How can I avoid this scrolling. I don't want any scrolling at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by setting `ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode` property to `Control`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="list" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode="Control" />
```